# How to make this accordion load with all menus closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

This is what I'm using: [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/davidxmartins/etfs1L43/39/)

I'd like to have all menus closed by default.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I know nothing of JavaScript so it would help if you illustrate your answer using the fiddle.

```
$('.info').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).toggleClass("open").next().slideToggle('fast');
    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass("open");
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/44/ see the updated fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etfs1L43/43/)

```
<div class='info'>
     <h1 class='accordion-toggle (remove this class ->)open'>Header 1 </h1>

    <div class='accordion-content (remove this class ->)default'>Content 1...</div>
     <h1 class='accordion-toggle'>Header 2 </h1>

    <div class='accordion-content'>Content 2...</div>
     <h1 class='accordion-toggle'>Header 3 </h1>

    <div class='accordion-content'>Content 3...</div>
</div>
```

There is no JS change needed just need to remove the open class in first H1 tag and default class form the div under it.

Comment: I feel a bit silly I didn't notice that. You answer was very clear and strait to the point. I got it immediately before you edit it with the code and fiddle. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

Remove "open" and "default"

```
<div class='info'>
     <h1 class='accordion-toggle'>Header 1 </h1>

    <div class='accordion-content'>Content 1...</div>
     <h1 class='accordion-toggle'>Header 2 </h1>

    <div class='accordion-content'>Content 2...</div>
     <h1 class='accordion-toggle'>Header 3 </h1>

    <div class='accordion-content'>Content 3...</div>
</div>
```

"open" class sets the header style to open and "default" sets the content as the content that shows by default before user interaction

Comment: "open" class sets the header style to open and "default" sets the content as the content that shows by default before user interaction.

Comment: Yes, *I* know; it's the OP that "*[knows] nothing of JavaScript.*" Plus any code explanation needs to be in the answer, where it's visible and easily read; not in the comments where formatting - such as it is - is atrocious for meaningful communication.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I just assumed it was obvious from the class names.